# Best way to render Tesselated Objects (OpenGL)

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I'm using the GLUTesselator for Polygons. Right now the vertex callback does glvertex2f and gltex2f. Would it be better simply to collect the verticies from the vertex callback in a std::vector then use gldrawarrays()? Or would this actually be less efficient since it has to put the verts and texture coordinates in a vector?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the vertex count on your tessellated objects is "sufficiently large" VAs/VBOs are almost always going to be faster than immediate-mode glBegin()/glEnd() code, especially if your geometry is static.